# Regular expression for numeric and '-' (Dash) characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to create a regular expression in asp.net which allows numeric values in following format

```
12-1234-5678-0000-1
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: That should be really trivial. Have you tried anything so far? Please show it. If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below regex will fulfill your requirements:

```
\d{2}-(?:\d{4}-){3}\d{1}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL9uR3/1)

```
\d{2} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
- matches the character - literally
(?:\d{4}-){3} Non-capturing group
Quantifier: {3} Exactly 3 times
\d{4} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {4} Exactly 4 times
- matches the character - literally
\d{1} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {1} Exactly 1 time (meaningless quantifier)
MATCH INFORMATION
```

Answer (score 0):

`string ip = "12-1234-5678-0000-1";
    Match m = Regex.Match(ip, @"^[\d]{2}\-[\d]{4}\-[\d]{4}\-[\d]{4}\-[\d]{1}$");
    Console.WriteLine(m.Success);`